# Python PyQt4 change image pressing button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel

I am trying to generate a visualizer where each time you press a button the image in a window change. The image have to be in the same window where the button is and it has to replace the previous image.

So for I am able to show the button and the first image. But I cannot connect the click button with the image updating process.
This is my code so far:

```
author__ = 'lpp'
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Test', 10))
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        # Show  image
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pic.setGeometry(10, 10, 800, 800)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( "/home/lpp/Desktop/Image1.png"))

        # Show button 
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(self.fun)
        btn.move(50, 50)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 2000, 1500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

    # Connect button to image updating 
    def fun(self):
       #print("Test!!!")
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pic.setGeometry(100, 10, 800, 800)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( "/home/lpp/Desktop/image2.png"))


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All but the "def fun" works.
I also tried these functions but it did not work:

```
    def fun(self):
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pic.setGeometry(100, 10, 800, 800)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( "/home/lpp/Desktop/image2.png"))
        return (pic)

    def fun(self):
       #print("Test!!!")
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pic.setGeometry(100, 10, 800, 800)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( "/home/lpp/Desktop/image2.png"))
        return self.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the previous image you should not create a new QLabel, but just update the QPixmap.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Test', 10))
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> widget')

        # Show  image
        self.pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic.setGeometry(10, 10, 800, 800)
        self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("/home/lpp/Desktop/image1.png"))

        # Show button 
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(self.fun)
        btn.move(50, 50)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 2000, 1500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tooltips')
        self.show()

    # Connect button to image updating 
    def fun(self):
        self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap( "/home/lpp/Desktop/image2.png"))

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```